# Удаленное управление WIndows Universal

Tags: c#, uwp

Подскажите как реализовать удаленное управление между приложением, запущенным на компьютере и на телефоне через локальную сеть. Я хочу, чтобы с телефона мог управлять воспроизведением в приложении, запущенном на компьютере.  Может статья какая есть где или пример?

Comment: из простого приходит в голову только WCF. Xamarin умеет простой http биндинг, а большего чтобы сделать "пульт" из телефона вродебы не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно клиент-серверное приложение. Приложение на компе будет выступать в роли сервера, ждать подключения и потом ждать команды от клиента. А с клиента, соответственно, подключение и отправка команд в виде http-запросов. В общем стандартное сетевое взаимодействие. Для медиацентра Kodi есть приложения для управления с w10m. Там опенсорс, можно посмотреть реализацию.

Comment: А может есть готовый клиент-серверный пакет на NuGet?

Comment: Кстати, прочитал про AppService. И вроде даже работает, но в рамках одного приложения и клиентскую и серверную логику + еще фоновая задача воспроизведения. Короче по итогу ничего не работает(